# How change font color for QMessageBox Label's?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtstylesheets, qlabel, qmessagebox

What I mean

```
QMessageBox::question, QMessageBox::warning, QMessageBox::critical, QMessageBox::Information { /* Base Text Size & Color */
font-size:12px;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

If I try `QmessageBox .QLabel` it's change font for all form/windows

end how add background if I use global setting for all

```
QDialog {
border-image: url(':/images/image') 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
```

it's set , but how set only for this QMessageBoxes.

This I understand , but  hv another problem, I add to background

```
QMessageBox QLabel {
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0, x2:0.5, y2:1, stop:0.5 rgba(0, 0, 0, 102));
border:0;
border-radius:6px;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
```

but it add to icon to   , how fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what are you exactly trying to do? You want to add a background for all QMessageBoxes? or for the QDialog?

Comment: I try change the font color for QMessageBox ( Dialog's ) end add to them custom background. If i use Globally  image for all QDialo's it's add  to QMessageBoxes dialog to. With font for QLabel the same.

Comment: The problem is - if set globally black image - it's make unreadable   black font  on QmessageBox critical, Info etc ... For all form change the font is simple but how with qss - set style for only this qmessageboxes,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
QMessageBox {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

QMessageBox QLabel {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

Comment: This I understand , but i hv another problem i add to background
QMessageBox QLabel {
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.5, y1:0, x2:0.5, y2:1, stop:0.5 rgba(0, 0, 0, 102));
border:0;
border-radius:6px;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}

but it add to icon to , how fix this ?

Comment: Where do you want to add the icon? Do you want to add an image to the message box?

Comment: For that you should use the "setIconPixmap(const QPixmap & pixmap)" function of the QMessageBox object. i.e.: messageBoxInstance.setIconPixmap(QPixMap(":/pictures/yourPic.jpg"));

Comment: How set icon i know

Comment: Isn't it your image that has a darker background? Maybe you can try photoshop to set the rest of the image to transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the color with tags inside the string passed as parameter to the QMessageBox:

```
QMessageBox::question(this, "Question", "<FONT COLOR='#ff0000'>Are you ready?</FONT>",
                                  QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
```

### [image: Question messageBox with font color red]

---

Answer (score 1):

```
setStyleSheet("QMessageBox{background: rgb(255,0,0);  border: none;font-family: Arial; font-style: normal;  font-size: 15pt; color: #000000 ; }");
```

result
[image]